# Linux host Why can't I ssh into host after adding myself to www-data group?

Tags: linux, nginx

I've setup a website on a EC2 Linux host (hosted by NGINX).  The directory `/var/www/html` has owner:group as `www-data:www-data`, so I figured I'd add myself to the `www-data` group so I was able to edit files without using `sudo`.

After adding me to the www-data group in /etc/group, I was no longer able to login to the host.  To add myself to the `www-data` group, I simply use vi as shown:

```
sudo vi /etc/group
www-data:x:33:myusername
```

At this point I found the group `www-data` and added my username to the end of the line.

I (fortunately) still had an ssh window open on the host so I removed myself from the `www-data` group and was able to ssh back into the host.  I tried adding myself to verify that this behavior was occurring and then removed myself again (so I could login again).

**Why does adding my user to the `www-data` group prevent me from logging on (via ssh) to the Linux host?**

### Looking for the answer

- Google search using https://www.google.com/search?q=purpose+of+www-data+group+in+linux comes up with

> www-data is the user that web servers on Ubuntu (Apache, nginx, for example) use by default for normal operation. The web server process can access any file that www-data can access. It has no other importance

So either that is wrong/old or there is some other reason this is happening.

Comment: Please include any error messages

Comment: Does the SSH server's configuration include a DenyGroups directive?

Comment: `After adding me to the www-data group in /etc/group` exactly how did you do that? like `sudo usermod -a -G www-data your-user-name`

Comment: @JaromandaX you can manually edit the file and add user(s) to certain group(s)

Comment: @annahri - I know you can, but perhaps OP made a mistake when doing so ... using usermod, mistakes can't be made.

Comment: I've updated the question to include how my username was added to the www-data group.  I simply edited the file `/etc/group`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the host had an add-on security system like SELinux or AppArmor enabled, or something like custom PAM rules or even just a very defensively configured `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, those security rules may have detected that your new session is a member of the `www-data` group. Usually only the child processes of a web server are expected to be members of that group.

If a web server child process attempts to run a shell, it could be a hacking attempt: since such processes need to accept unauthenticated, potentially-malicious requests from the internet, a previously unknown vulnerability in their code might allow an intruder to exploit them to cause them to run malicious code, and so place the process under intruder's control.

The obvious next step in the intrusion process would be the hijacked process to launch a shell session for the intruder, so it makes a certain kind of sense that a "hardened" web server might have a security rule that blocks `www-data` group members from having shell sessions.

Without knowing any more details, it is hard to say for sure, but it is possible that you were stopped by a security feature like this.